# How do you get the currently selected <option> in a <select> via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How do you get the *currently* selected `<option>` of a `<select>` element via JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: @AndersonGreen: that isn’t *quite* the same question. It’s actually asking how to get the text of the selection `<option>`.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
var yourSelect = document.getElementById( "your-select-id" );
alert( yourSelect.options[ yourSelect.selectedIndex ].value )
```

Comment: if you use it to access the value of the option, you may as well just use `yourSelect.value`.  Very old, archaic browsers might not support it, but IE6 and every modern browser does.

Comment: @Andy E: ooh, there’s an idea — that is indeed what I’m doing, and your code is a bit easier to read.

Comment: @Andy E: ah, one caveat about that method — it doesn’t return the text of the `<option>` element in IE, I think you need to have something in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 27):

The [`.selectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534624(VS.85).aspx) of the `select` object has an index; you can use that to index into the `.options` array.

Comment: This is the most elegant and straightforward approach

Answer (score 5):

Using the `selectedOptions` property:

```
var yourSelect = document.getElementById("your-select-id");
alert(yourSelect.selectedOptions[0].value);
```

It [works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions#Browser_compatibility) in all browsers except Internet Explorer.

Comment: “It works in all browsers except Internet Explorer.” As soon as everyone stops using Internet Explorer, we’re golden! [Possible polyfill here](https://gist.github.com/brettz9/4212217).

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have multiple selection
You can do it like.

```
var yourSelect = document.getElementById( "your-select-id" );
alert(yourSelect.selectedOptions[0].value)
```

Will do the same thing like the choosen answer. Since `.selectedOptions` gives you a list of selected options elements

Comment: Sure, although it's already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48534292/20578)