# html - how to get custom attribute of option tag in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, select

If I have this code:

```
 <select onchange="alert('?');" name="myname" class="myclass"> 
    <option isred="-1" value="hi">click</option>
 </select>
```

How can I get the value '-1' from the custom attribute isred ?
I don't want to use the value property.
And I dont want to target the option tag by a name or id.

I want something like `onchange="alert(this.getselectedoptionID.getAttribute('isred'));"`

Can anyone help?

Also I don't want to use jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the currently selected <option> in a <select> via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301688/how-do-you-get-the-currently-selected-option-in-a-select-via-javascript) -- it seems you know how to get attribute, just not how to get the selected option... well, that's covered in that question.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You need to figure out what the selectedIndex is, then `getAttribute` from that options[] Array.

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('isred'));" name="myname" class="myclass"> 
    <option isred="-1" value="hi">click</option>
    <option isred="-5" value="hi">click</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sp6dQ/)

### **As a side note:**

**Don't use inline javascript** in your `HTML`. You want to separate your business logic from your UI. Create a javascript event handlers instead to handle this. (jQuery / Angular / etc)

Comment: @Mark Pieszak, Imagine I have this code:
`<input onchange="update(this.value, this.getAttribute('code'))" value="1" id="quantity_1001" code="1001" type="number">`
What better way do you suggest instead of inline onchange declaration? I want values to be passed in as parameters! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @ShahedBinSatter Set up the change event in the javascript

Comment: How do I pass the values (this.value and this.getAttribute('code')) as parameters?

Comment: `onchange="myFunc(this.value, this.getAttribute('code'))"` with "myFunc" being a `function myFunc(val, code) { /* do something */ }` in your actual JS code. Ideally don't even use the `onchange` method, and setup that onchange method in the JS itself, but that's a separate concept, but you can look that up online and see how it's done! Hope that helps. Cheers

Answer (score 32):

in jquery, you can just write:

```
$("#myname").find(':selected').attr('isred');
```

Comment: OP says explicitly that s/he doesn't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Glad you wrote it, because it helped me :)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This should have been marked as the Correct answer

Answer (score 8):

Use something like this:

```
document.getElementById("x").onchange = function () {
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("isred"));
};
```

Comment: What if I want to get a custom attribute when the form is being submitted?

Answer (score 5):

```js
//Pure Javascript solution, and elegant one check if you really want to leverage the power of javascript.

// Listening to a onchange event by ID attached with the select tag.
document.getElementById("name_your_id").onchange = function(event) {

//event.target.selectedOptions[0] have that option. as this is single selection by dropdown. this will always be 0th index :) 
let get_val = event.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("isred");
console.log("Value from the Attribute: ", get_val)
}
```

```html
 <select id="name_your_id" name="myname" class="myclass">
    <option isred="423423" value="hi">One</option>
    <option isred="-1" value="hi">Two</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we have a `HTML` markup as below:

```
<form id="frm_">
    <select name="Veh">
        <option value='-1' selected='selected'>Select</option>
        <option value='0' ren='x'>xxx</option>
        <option value='1' ren='y'>yyy</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The `attr "ren"` can be accessed like this:

```
function getRep() {
    var ren = document.forms['frm_'].elements['Veh'].options[document.forms['frm_']
                 .elements['Veh'].selectedIndex].getAttribute('ren');
    console.log("Val of ren " + ren); //x or y
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4fpaaxgy/)

Comment: the code provided by you had errors which needs to be addressed before you post it for others to use. Your answer would be more helpful if you post your important piece of code with the answer rather than user's navigating to your jsfiddle link. As of now I have done it on behalf of you.

Answer (score 1):

You use: `.getAttribute('isred')`

You want:

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('isred'));" name="myname" class="myclass">
    <option isred="-1" value="hi">click</option>
    <option isred="-1" value="ho">click</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you mean like
onchange="alert(.getAttribute('isred'));" ?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55967089/7481350). But I still want to add it because it specifically shows how to get the *data* attribute.

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option data-test="123" value="a">A</option>
  <option data-test="456" value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
const select = document.querySelector('#mySelect');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.selectedOptions[0].dataset.test);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you can

```
$(".myclass").val(function(){alert($("option",this).attr("isred"));})
```

Comment: This always alerts the value of the first option's (as opposed to the selected one) isred attribute, it deselects the selected option, and the question says **not** to use jQuery.