# How to retrieve data from custom attribute on option tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with a select dropdown with options that are built by looping over an object. Each option has an associated `value` attribute and a custom attribute `data`.

I can retrieve the `value` just fine but I cannot access the `data` attribute. I tried following a JavaScript pattern found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957677/html-how-to-get-custom-attribute-of-option-tag-in-dropdown) but to no avail. The value returned is `undefined`.

Here is the component with the form:

```
import React from 'react';
import Option from './Option';

class AddmenuItemForm extends React.Component {
  createMenuItemTest(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const menuItem = {
      subsectionObjectId: this.subsectionObjectId.value,
      orderIndex: this.subsectionObjectId.selectedIndex.data,
    }

    this.props.addMenuItem(menuItem);

    this.menuItemForm.reset();
  }

  render() {
    const { subsections } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form ref={(input) => this.menuItemForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => this.createMenuItemTest(e)}>
          <select
            ref={(input) => this.subsectionObjectId = input}
            className="input mtm">
            {
              Object
                .keys(subsections)
                .map(key => <Option key={key} id={key} details={subsections[key]} />)
            }
          </select>

          <button type="submit">Add New</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default AddmenuItemForm;
```

And here is the Option component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Option extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { details } = this.props;
    const key = this.props.id;

    return (
      <option value={key} data={details.numberMenuItems}>
        {details.name}
      </option>
    )
  }
}

export default Option;
```

Rendered HTML looks like this (the `<select>` portion):

```
<select>
  <option value="KhEncads5F" data="11">Lunch</option>
  <option value="rxGeTpqSDF" data="2">Dinner</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the extra piece of info on the selected `<option>` tag?

Comment: You can use `ref` to obtain a reference to the DOM node and use the answer from the SO post you linked in your question.

Comment: Why bother storing data in DOM? You could always access `details` using `subsections[this.subsectionObjectId.value]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `ref` you have to your `DOM` element you can access the  and the `selectedOptions`:

```
this.subsectionObjectId.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-items')
```

Check this working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/1rmftx4z/

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! **Note to others**: my original post had a typo and was using `data-items` and `data` interchangeably for the custom attribute.

Comment: Hi, I am getting console log for the *value* attr of `option` tag, but it is giving me an `undefined` for *data* attr of it's console log as i am doing the same thing for both so why the data attr is undefined ? 
https://gist.github.com/mrudangshah/ed86f242e4be6a57cc2eb85fa254b2eb