# Selected Option Attributes to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, api

I have a wordpress theme using autocomplete suggestion by getJSON,suggestion call into a drop down option like below

[image]

And the inspect view is below 
[image]

I want save the ID and value of the selected option into a variable, How can i do it please help.

Thanks

Comment: Check the documentation of the select plugin you're using. I would imagine it has a method to build a string/object/array from the selected values

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then you can use `attr()`

Check the documentation http://api.jquery.com/attr/

try this code:

```
$('#element option:selected').attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks , but can it called directly via a JS because string is controlled by a java script

Comment: there are many example on the site you can find. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957677/html-how-to-get-custom-attribute-of-option-tag-in-dropdown

Comment: var destination = form.find('select[name="destination"] option:selected').val();

This how the destination name called to the string, i to call the attribute value to a var