# Get Id of option instead of getting value on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I need to get "ID" of option instead of value.

Example.

```
<select id="industry">
<option id ="1" value="11">one</option>
<option id ="2" value="22">Two</option>
</select>
```

I know I can get values using the following

```
$("#industry").on("change",function(){
   var GetValue=$("#industry").val(); 
});
```

Is the any option to get Id

Comment: You should probably use `data-id="1"` then `$(..).data("id")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `var GetValue=$("#industry option:selected").attr("id");` to do it.

Explaination:

- `#industry`: Will look for element with id `industry`
- `#industry option`: Will look for options under `industry` dropdown
- `option:selected`: Will look for selected option. `:selected` is an attribute selector that looks for selected attribute in element

Once you have element, you can retrieve the `id` property from it.

```js
$("#industry").on("change",function(){
 var GetValue=$("#industry option:selected").attr("id");
 alert(GetValue)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="industry">
<option id ="1" value="11">one</option>
<option id ="2" value="22">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer. Please revert if not required

Comment: @Rajesh It's my pleasure for you to edit my answer,thanks once again

Comment: Being picky:  `:selected` https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/ is a jQuery extension for `<option>` elements.  Saying it's an "attribute selector" implies it can be used for other elements, or that it could be used for other attributes, such as `:required`

Comment: @freedomn-m Hmmm,since the OP is using `jQuery` so I posted my answer using `jQuery`,if want to pure `js` soultion,I think [html-how-to-get-custom-attribute-of-option-tag-in-dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957677/html-how-to-get-custom-attribute-of-option-tag-in-dropdown) will be helpful

Comment: @lucumt I have no issue with using jquery, not sure why you even mention pure js and tagged me.   I'm highlighting the misleading description of `:selected` as *:selected is an attribute selector that looks for selected attribute in element*  - which is misleading.