# Display a select option based on other select option

Tags: php, html, ajax

```
<select name = "team1">
  <option>Computer Science</option>
  <option>Mathematics</option>
  <option>Bioinformatic</option>
  <option>Management Sciences</option>
</select>
<select name = "team2">
  <option>Computer Science</option>
  <option>Mathematics</option>
  <option>Bioinformatic</option>
  <option>Management Sciences</option>
</select>
```

how can i use the above code as depending "team2" on what value "team1" have.If i select computer science in the select option of team 1, then i don't want computer science to appear in the options of "team2".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?
Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give an ID to your selection and check the selection of the specific element. Thus you can distinguish between team1 and team2 and remove some in team2-selection with same value. it could be something like this:

```
<body>
 <select onChange="jsFunction()" id="team1" >
      <option onclick="jsFunction()">Computer Science</option>
      <option>Mathematics</option>
      <option>Bioinformatic</option>
      <option>Management Sciences</option>
    </select>

    <select id="team2">
      <option>Computer Science</option>
      <option>Mathematics</option>
      <option>Bioinformatic</option>
      <option>Management Sciences</option>
    </select>

    <script>
    function jsFunction(){
        var team1 = document.getElementById( "team1" );
        var team2 = document.getElementById( "team2" );
        for (i=0;i<4;i++){
            team2.remove(0);
        }
        var position=0;
        for (i=0;i<4;i++){
            if (i!=team1.selectedIndex){
            team2.options[position] = new Option(team1.options[i].value);
            position=position+1;
            }
        }

    }
    </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: You can find solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301688/how-do-you-get-the-currently-selected-option-in-a-select-via-javascript and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: i wrote it like   <html>
 <head>
  <script>
    var team1 = document.getElementById( "team1" );
    alert( team1.options[ team1.selectedIndex ].value );
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <select name = "team1" id="team1">
  <option>Computer Science</option>
  <option>Mathematics</option>
  <option>Bioinformatic</option>
  <option>Management Sciences</option>
 </select>
 <select name = "team2" id="team2">
  <option>Computer Science</option>
  <option>Mathematics</option>
  <option>Bioinformatic</option>
  <option>Management Sciences</option>
 </select>

 </body>
</html>

Comment: you have to add the script-part into body after the definition of the selection. I edited my post

Comment: now it works only for 1st option, only computer science option is not showing in "team2", should i use AJAX to do it without submitting form?If Yes then could you please give me a hint?

Comment: You don't need any AJAX or PHP. I edited my post again, so that an adjustment of the values of team2 is made as soon as the selection of team1 changes.

Comment: you're welcome. You can accept the answer, if you think it's the most useful one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Checkbox for these options.Its solves your Problem.

Comment: but i want to use it in select options,

Answer (score 0):

why PHP?

http://jsfiddle.net/655noe6p/

HTML:

```
<select name = "team1">
</select>
<select name = "team2">
</select>
```

JS:

```
var l = [
    'Computer Science',
    'Mathematics',
    'Bioinformatic',
    'Management Sciences'
];

$('select').change(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var other = me.siblings();

    var text = me.children(':selected').text();

    other.each(function() {
        var select = $(this);

        var currentText = select.children(':selected').text();
        select.empty();
        $.each(l, function(k, d) {
            if(d != text) {
                select.append($('<option></option>').html(d).attr('selected', d == currentText));
            }
        });
    });
});

$('select').change().change();
```

Comment: will the JS be in body tag after select?

Comment: yes in <script> tags and you have to include jquery, too

Comment: how to include jquery?

Comment: sorry to bother you again and again, i am actually not much familiar with j query and java script, but i use it little bit.

Comment: can you google how to include jquery. that would be very nice of you. You will find more, than I can tell you here.

Comment: yeah , but what should the jquery file contain?

Comment: The code I wrote for you uses jQuery. jQuery is a small toolkit for ugly DOM operations. It's a working code from google you have to include. The $()... calls is jquery.

Comment: could you please email me the complete page for that code, i totally got stuck tanveer.ashraf40@hotmail.com

Comment: you don't want to try it? Where is your effort? come on