# Javascript delete function from a select

Tags: javascript, api, selected

I created an API with Node.js express and mongodb, working perfectly fine.

I have a delete function that works fine as well.

I have an empty HTML select, and I generate the different options by a performing a get request that create all options that I have in my mongodb database.

I would like to delete the selected option in my select but I'm struggling to find a way to get the id of the specific select option.

HTML

```
<select id="content-dropdown">
  
</select>
```

JS :

```
 function showGames(url){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let i = 0;
            
            for(i in response){
              dropdown.innerHTML += '<option value="'+response[i].title+'" id="'+response[i]._id+'" class="game">'+response[i].title+'</option>';
            }
            
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send();
  }
```

I managed to get all the id but when I use the delete function it delete the last option in the select.

I tried onchange / onclick event on the select but didn't manage to get it working.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to delete the option. Also note that using `for..in` over an array is [well, a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/215552).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the currently selected <option> in a <select> via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301688/how-do-you-get-the-currently-selected-option-in-a-select-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the identifier as the option value: `value="'response[i]._id'"` then listen to the `onchange` event of the `select` element and retrieve the current value with `event.target.value` in order to call the backend.